# Zeros in a vector field

Tags: general-topology

I am reading the book "Euler's Gem: The Polyhedron Formula and the Birth of Topology" by David Richeson. In one of the chapters, it is mentioned that the number of indices of zeros in a vector field on a surface gives the Eular characteristics of that surface. Hence it is stated that the Eular characteristics of a sphere is two. But I could not understand why EVERY vector field on a sphere contains two zero vectors?

Answer (score 1):

The Euler characteristic on a surface $S$ is defined by $\sum_{X(x)=0}i(x)$ where $X$ is a vector field defined on $X$ with isolated singularities and $i(x)$ is the index of $X$ at the singularity $x$. You can have more than one singularitie, since the index can be negative.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem

Comment: You can also have exactly one (rather than two) singularities as seen, for instance, [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Hairy_ball_one_pole.jpg).

Comment: Thank you for the example you provided. But why a vector field on a sphere must have at least one singularity?

Comment: yes, since the euler characteristic of the sphere is $2$.

Comment: It seems that one can form a vector field on a sphere by assigning a vector to each point of the sphere all with different directions. I can't see how such a "vector field" has a singular point and hence a zero vector.